# Most auspicious times for bathing in Mikve according to Kabbalah

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mysticism-kabbalah, mikvah-ritual-bath, practical-kabbalah

I am interested in the Kabbalistic answer to this question (below) because of my interest in the deeper spiritual experience and philosophical knowledge, but if you know of an answer according to Halacha, then please feel free to answer as well.

Are there certain spiritual effects which are unique to bathing in a Mikvah in the morning, evening or midday? If it's possible to give the reasons for this, I would greatly appreciate it.

If there is a different answer for men and women, this question deals with men.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The most auspicious time to bathe in the mikva is immediately after it is cleaned.

Comment: Haha ok... Is this question somehow out of line for this website?

Comment: It is a good question and perfectly in line. I just don't have a real answer, though there is something to be said about dipping in the morning to one can start shacharis "pure"

Answer (score 2):

This question has many possible answers. At different times in history, circumstances were different. And so the answer, depending on where you look could vary. But it seems most appropriate to offer the kabbalistic answer most appropriate for this time.

This can be found from the Ba'al Shem Tov as written in Keter Shem Tov, page 3:3. It is preferred that one immerse as frequently as possible and in particular in times of need.

[http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&st=מקוה&pgnum=39&hilite=ca15e256-b209-4975-9ab3-db97bc3ce296](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&st=%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%94&pgnum=39&hilite=ca15e256-b209-4975-9ab3-db97bc3ce296)

On page 125, chapter 219, the Ba'al Shem Tov attributes all the revelations and levels to which he attained being the result of immersion in the mikvah constantly. He emphasizes that frequent immersion (יותר בתמידות) is more beneficial than frequent fasting. He says this is because fasting weakens the physical body from being able to serve HaShem. He says that it is better to take the strength that one would lose through fasting and direct it toward increased Torah study and prayer with proper kavannah with all ones might.

[http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&st=מקוה&pgnum=161&hilite=ca15e256-b209-4975-9ab3-db97bc3ce296](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&st=%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%94&pgnum=161&hilite=ca15e256-b209-4975-9ab3-db97bc3ce296)

Additionally, on page 409, chapter 254, he emphasizes that in particular it is beneficial to immerse on erev Shabbat and Yom Tov and also on Shabbat and Yom Tov morning because it gives one 'hope' (a play on words for 'mikvah'). He says immersion at those times is a segulah for praying with kavannah and for cleaving with G-d.

[http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&st=מקוה&pgnum=443&hilite=ca15e256-b209-4975-9ab3-db97bc3ce296](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&st=%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%94&pgnum=443&hilite=ca15e256-b209-4975-9ab3-db97bc3ce296)

In regard to the different 'spiritual effects' relating to the different times of day, these are according to some sources, like Sefer Raziel HaMalach, divided into four categories. Each of these four time periods corresponds to the predominant influence of the corresponding names of 72, 63, 45 and 52 as well as 161, 161, 143 and 151. A discussion that may answer some of your questions concerning this can be found at the section of Keter Shem Tov explaining the Kavannot for immersing in the mikvah according to the Ba'al Shem Tov. A link follows.

[http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&hilite=ca15e256-b209-4975-9ab3-db97bc3ce296&st=מקוה&pgnum=41](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&hilite=ca15e256-b209-4975-9ab3-db97bc3ce296&st=%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%94&pgnum=41)

Concerning the subject of men and women, the general custom today is that women who have not yet been married do not immerse. But the reasoning behind that has nothing to do with concept here. Strictly speaking, both men and women benefit from this practice in the same way. There are some women today who immerse more frequently than once a month.

Comment: Yaacov thank you very much for your well thought out answer. From my experience of immersion in Mikvah, it has been clear to me that there must be a lot of wisdom behind it. I'm glad to see how much it is encouraged. I will look at the texts found from your web links for more information on the 4 periods of the day, frequency, bath doing those days such as Shabbat, etc.